# Adding slider to Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, slider, asset-pipeline, erb

I am having trouble adding a simple slider to my rails 3 application.  There don't seem to be any errors in my JavaScript:

My Gemfile has:

```
gem 'jquery-rails'

group :assets do
  gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
end
```

skills.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
  $('#slider').slider
```

skills/show.html.erb:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .
```

It does not show up in my application.  Are there any other steps which I need to take to make it show up?

Thanks

Comment: Does the console show your coffee script file has loaded?

Comment: Ah, do you have the stylesheets loaded as well? I'm not at my laptop just yet but think you need them.

Comment: Thanks that works!  `*= require jquery.ui.slider` in application.css

Comment: Hey, glad to hear it! And thanks for the plus one. Should have put it in an answer though ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Needed to add jquery ui to css.

Add the following to `application.css`

```
*= require jquery.ui.slider
```

Thanks to simonmorley for solution

Comment: Also, if you're specifying individual jquery components, rather than the the full //= require jquery-ui (eg if you're mixing Bootstrap & JQuery which sometimes gives probs, eg with datepicker I think) then adding //= require jquery.ui.slider to application.js will work